# How use 2 controllers in one input

Tags: html, angularjs

Need get data from ControllerB and use selected in ControllerA

```
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="All" selectpicker
                          ng-model="ControllerA.Criteria.Status"
                          ng-options="item as item.DISPLAY for item in ControllerB.ComboStatusListResult">
                  </select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you'll want to consider moving shared data into a service or factory to prevent exactly this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best possible solution is to use data transfer services in angular js to get the `ComboStatusListResult` in `ControllerB` to `ControllerA` and there after using the options from `ControllerA` itself.

Sample data transfer service.

```
myApp.factory('DataTransfer', function () {

    var data = {
        Options: ''
    };

    return {
        getOptions: function () {
            return data.Options;
        },
        setOptions: function (Options) {
            data.Options= Options;
        }
    };
});
```

and from `ControllerB` set the `ComboStatusListResult` object to the service.

```
myApp.controller('ControllerB', function ($scope, DataTransfer) {

    DataTransfer.setOptions($scope.ComboStatusListResult);

});
```

and in `ControllerA` receive the options to its scope object

```
myApp.controller('ControllerA', function ($scope, DataTransfer) {

    $cope.ComboStatusListResult = DataTransfer.getOptions();

});
```

and in your template use it as.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" title="All" selectpicker
        ng-model="Criteria.Status"
        ng-options="item as item.DISPLAY for item in ComboStatusListResult"></select>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please approve this as answer if you think this was what you want.